# object file format invalid or unsuitable

Tags: iphone, xcode, codesign

I have two Xcode installed on my iMac (OSX 10.6.8), Xcode 3.1.4 and Xcode 3.2.6.
I created a new „empty view” project, it builds and runs in simulator fine with both Xcode.

BUT when I want to build to DEVICE then I got this error in Xcode 3.2.6:

.../build/Debug-iphoneos/JustaTest.app: object file format invalid or unsuitable
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

It still works fine in Xcode 3.1.4 but it seems that the JustaTest.app file generated by Xcode 3.2.6 is not compatible with codesign.

Does anyone know how to tell Xcode 3.2.6 to generate codesign compatible app file?
Or how to get a new codesign which can sign app files generated by Xcode 3.2.6?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you set up `Code Signing identity` in `Build Settings`?

Comment: Yes, of curse. Othervise it wouldn't work at all. But it works fine in Xcode 3.1.4 I have this error only in Xcode 3.2.6.

Comment: FIXED/ The soultion is here: https://devforums.apple.com/message/559109#559109

Comment: sudo ln -s /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate /usr/bin

Comment: You should put the solution as a proper answer so people can vote it up. I almost missed this!

Comment: _And_ you can get the reputation points for the answer too! Not that points matter or anything... ;) Your post helped me out.